# C++ get file names of files causing directory changed notifications

Tags: c++, qt, filesystems, filesystemwatcher

I am currently looking for a solution to find files that have been added, deleted, changed or rename within a directory that I am watching.

I am using C++ QT 5.1.1 on Windows 7.However, a "relatively" system independet solution would be nice. I have looked through QT, which only offers a DirectoryWatcher showing me if a directory changed - NOT - WHAT changed. (I need the WHAT part). POCO offers the same in their filesystem area. Boost does not seem to support this neither.

In the MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.created(v=vs.110).aspx

Taken from the example:

```
 // Define the event handlers. 
   static void OnChanged( Object^ /*source*/, FileSystemEventArgs^ e )
   {
      // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
      Console::WriteLine( "File: {0} {1}", e->FullPath, e->ChangeType );
   }

   static void OnRenamed( Object^ /*source*/, RenamedEventArgs^ e )
   {
      // Specify what is done when a file is renamed.
      Console::WriteLine( "File: {0} renamed to {1}", e->OldFullPath, e->FullPath );
   }
```

Is there a way to use this in my QT application or have a more "natural" C++ approach?

All help is apprechiated. 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The [`QFileSystemWatcher`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qfilesystemwatcher.html) class does some of what you need, although it is limited in what it can do. It doesn't, for example, offer detailed rename/move notifications.